# Detalle de un item de diferentes modelos en entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework

La verdad soy nuevo programando y constantemente encuentro problemas, actualmente tengo una tabla en la que coloco datos relacionados con estudiantes casa fila tiene un boton que me permite ver mas informacion relacionada con el estudiante pero tambien existe informacion relacionada en otras tablas como por ejemplo la tabla ciudad, tabla estado y tabla pais al que pertenece el estudiante. pero esta informacion no se como mostrarla en el detalle, ya que cuando el controlador hace la busqueda solo me pasa informacion del modelo UserSchool y no de las tablas con las que esta relacionada.
la clase estudiante es la siguiente:

```
public class UserSchool
{

    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "E-Mail")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is required")]
    [StringLength(50)]//only you can to write 50 characters
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    // [Index("UserNameIndex", Isnique = true)]
    public string EmailUser { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nombres")]
    [Required]
    public string FirstNameUser { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Apellidos")]
    [Required]
    public string LastNameUser { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.FirstNameUser, this.LastNameUser); }
    }
    [Display(Name = "Telefono")]
    public string PhoneUser { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Direccion de residencia")]
    [Required]
    public string AddressUser { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Fecha de nacimiento")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]// para que nos muestre el calendario
    public DateTime DateBirthdayUser{ get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Imagen")]
    public string PhotoUser { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Estudiante")]
    public bool IsStudentUser { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Profesor")]
    public bool IsTeacherUser { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sistemas")]
    public bool IsSystemUser { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Numero de documento")]
    public string NumberDocumentUsers { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tipo de documento")]
    public int TypeDocumentId { get; set; }
    public virtual TypeDocument TypeDocument { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Pais de nacimiento")]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Departamento de nacimiento")]
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public virtual State State { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Ciudad de nacimento")]
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public virtual City City { get; set; }  




}
```

La clase pais

```
 public class Country
{

    [Key]
    public int CountryId { get; set; } 

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nombre pais")]
    public string NameCountry { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserSchool> UserSchools { get; set; }


}
```

La clase Estado

```
 public class State
{
    [Key]
    public int StateId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nombre Departamento")]
    public string NameState { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Pais")]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserSchool> UserSchools { get; set; }


}
```

La clase ciudad

public class City
    {
        [Key]
        public int CityId { get; set; }

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nombre Ciudad")]
    public string NameCity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public virtual State State { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<UserSchool> UserSchools { get; set; }
}
```

El web controler que envia la informacion

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        UserSchool userSchool = await db.UserSchools.FindAsync(id);


        if (userSchool == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(userSchool);
    }
```

La vista detalle donde quiero mostrar tanto informacion del estudiante como tambien el nombre de la ciudad, nombre del departamento y nombre del pais.

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-hover">

        <tr>
            <td><b>Tipo Documento</b></td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.City.NameCity)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Numero Documento</b></td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NumberDocumentUsers)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Nombre Completo</b></td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FullName)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Correo electronico</b></td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EmailUser)n</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Direccion</b></td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AddressUser)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Telefono</b></td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PhoneUser)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Estudiante</b></td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IsStudentUser)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Profesor</b></td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IsTeacherUser)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Administrativo</b></td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IsSystemUser)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Fecha de nacimiento</b></td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateBirthdayUser)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Lugar de nacimiento</b></td>
            <td>


            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: No trae las entidades relacionadas por el hecho de que no estan relacionadas.. tenes que usar [llaves foráneas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856218/understanding-foreignkey-attribute-in-entity-framework-code-first) para eso

Comment: si la Clase UserSchool tiene llaves foraneas de city, state y country. Estan relacionadas

Comment: Entonces completa la pregunta con esa información porfavor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework por defecto no trae las entidades relacionadas cuando haces un query (si fuera así cargaría la relación de la relación y ¡terminaría cargando toda la base de datos!).  Tienes que ser explícito con que relaciones quieres traer en el mismo query.  Una manera es con `Include`

```
using System.Data.Entity;

// ...

var userSchool = await db.UserSchools
                         .Include(x => x.Country)
                         .Include(x => x.City)
                         .Include(x => x.State)
                         .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserId == id);
```

Comment: No me funciona la verdad me aparace un error

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ulhf.png

Comment: Me olvidé que `FindAsync` no está disponible cuando sea `Include`.  Lo cambié por FirstOrDefaultAsync.

Comment: Si ahora si me funciono, gracias de verdad por aportar tus conocimientos.

Answer (score 0):

He intentado hacerlo de esta forma:

```
using System.Data.Entity;



var userSchool = await db.UserSchools
                     .Include(x => x.Country)
                     .Include(x => x.City)
                     .Include(x => x.State)
                     .FindAsync(id);
```

Pero tengo este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que para devolver datos del controlador a la vista no utilices la clase que te da por defecto Entity Framework, sino que la mapees a otra clase ViewModel especifica para mostrar los datos que necesitas.

De esta manera con EF traes con los includes todos los datos que necesitas y los mapeas a esta nueva clase ViewModel que te va a servir para mostrar los datos en la vista.

Esta es la mejor manera de no complicarse la vida el modelo de base de datos y la vista.

Espero te sirva el consejo.